# How to zoom to point and place a pin?

Tags: qgis

Is there any means to combine the function of zoom to point and place a pin plugins in QGIS? Would it be possible to enter a xy co-ordinate and a pinpoint is placed at the point of the grid reference. My apologies if I have missed something obvious on other forums. GSherman maintains these both so I am hoping this query reaches him!?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, this doesnt seem like a general feature. so i think there will be no plugin providing this functionality. but if you are ready to code you can have this very easily.

QGIS API provides methods to goto a particular coordinates while you hit it on the "coordinates" box in status bar. so you can write a plugin where you can choose a location and marker symbol. which will be drawn on map canvas at the chosen point. Hope there is api call to draw a image on the iface.mapCanvas()

Comment: rashad, thanks for the reply unfortunately I would have to call myself very much an end-user. I will certainly look at API but I dont hold out hope!! My hope is that there is some simple way to combine the functionality of these two existing plugins

Comment: which are the two existing plugins?

Comment: Hi the plugins are zoom to point and place a pin